# matplotlib - how to use sliders to change my graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I have some experimental data which I've plotted on some nice looking graphs with matplotlib (it's data of microlensing stars from the centre of Andromeda if you're interested)
The graphs look something like this: (only larger and on a pdf)
[image: Graph of microlensing event]

The (mathematical) function isn't quite right, so I would like to add a slider to change the parameters of the (mathematical) function (the blue line) like the amplitude of the sine wave and the phase and the height of the peak etc. There are seven parameters in total. How would I go about doing this? Thanks.

[The full code is here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6972140/)

The (python) function that returns the y axis values is here:

```
def mysinfunction(fbase, deltaf, t0, thalf, amplitude, T, phase, x):
    A = fbase+(deltaf/(math.sqrt(1+12*((x-t0)/thalf)**2)))+(amplitude*math.sin((2*pi*x/T)-phase))
    return A
```

and these are plotted by taking regular intervals on the time axis and feeding those points into the (python) function `mysinfunction`, then storing as a list and plotting that list against the time axis:

```
i = 0
while (i < n):
    xfunction.append(i*interval+xData[0])
    i = i + 1

i = 0
while (i < n):
    x = float(xfunction[i])
    if (ans == "y"):
        yfunction.append(mysinfunction(fbase, deltaf, t0, thalf, amplitude, T, phase, x))
    else:
        yfunction.append(myfunction(fbase, deltaf, t0, thalf, x))
    i = i + 1
```

Also adding a button to click after (that would run a reduced chi squared function and output the value with the new values for amplitude etc) would be awesome too.
I know this is a big ask, but I hope someone can help me make a start on this, thank you.

Comment: You can do this with mpl widgets (see http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) or do a proper embedding in the gui frame work of your choice.

Comment: @tcaswell
Could you explain how in an answer? I don't quite understand the notation in that example and it's the only example I could find anywhere.